# How to create a constraint on a field and the date value of created_at in django?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to create a constraint that allows an instance of a value for a field to exist only once per day. Meaning if I have a column custom_id and a created_at field, an example value '1' of custom_id
can only exist once on 2023-01-01, so adding another field will fail.

I am using postgres as a database and from what I have gathered, a query similar to

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (custom_id WITH =, date_trunc('day', created_at) WITH =)
```

However I am failing to replicate this in a django model according to the available

Comment: Why not `UNIQUE(custom_id, date_trunc('day', created_at))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        # Check if an instance with the same name already exists on the same day
        queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(name=self.name, date=self.date)
        if self.pk:
            queryset = queryset.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        if queryset.exists():
            raise ValidationError('An instance with the same name already exists on this day')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['name', 'date'], name='unique_instance_per_day')
        ]
```

In the above code, custom clean method has been defined for the model. This method is automatically called whenever the model is validated. Inside the method, check if an instance with the same name already exists on the same date. If an instance already exists, raise a ValidationError. Also exclude the current instance from the queryset if it's being updated.

Additionally, define a UniqueConstraint in the model's Meta class to enforce the constraint at the database level. This constraint ensures that only one instance with the same name and date can exist in the database at the same time.

With this implementation, you can create and save instances of MyModel, but if an instance with the same name and date already exists, it will raise a validation error and prevent the instance from being saved.

Hope it helps.